# Flutter: Vertically center a widget in a `Card`

Tags: flutter

I have a `Card` with a fixed height and I want to vertically center a widget inside that card. I tried multiple variations and the only way to achieve my goal is to put the widget inside of a shrink-wrapping `Row`, which feels a bit overkill.

Is there any simpler way to achieve the following?

```
Card(
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    height: 48,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Text("Correct"),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Full example code with attempts:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Card(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                height: 48,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Text("Correct"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 48),
            Card(
              child: Container(
                height: 48,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: const Text("Wrong"),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 48),
            Card(
              child: Container(
                height: 48,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text("Wrong"),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 48),
            Card(
              child: Container(
                height: 48,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Row(
                  children: const [
                    Text("Wrong"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot of full example:

[image: Screenshot of full example]

Comment: You can also use a `Column` with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` but this is not very different from your working `Row` example. I don't think there is a simpler way without setting an explicit width for the container.

Comment: I agree with @PeterKoltai, basically the card being in column is free to expand horizontally. Without any constraints you cannot achieve it.

Comment: Instead of `Row` you can use the `UnconstrainedBox` widget.

Answer (score 0):

The goal can be achieved by using `Align` with a `widthFactor = 1`:

```
Card(
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    height: 48,
    child: const Align(
      widthFactor: 1,
      child: Text("Correct"),
    ),
  ),
)
```

This yields:

[image: Card with horizontally aligned child]

Setting the `widthFactor` of `Align` will force `Align` to size its width to the width of its child multiplied by the factor instead of the parents width.